# normal bundles are stably isotopic

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I am searching for a reference about the following theorem:

Let $M \xrightarrow{i_{0}} \mathbb{R}^{k},\,\,$ $M \xrightarrow{i_{1}} \mathbb{R}^{l}$ be two embeddings of the manifold $M$. We know by the tubular neighborhood theorem that these embeddings extend to embeddings of the normal bundles $E(\nu_{0})\xrightarrow{j_{0}}\mathbb{R}^{k},\,\,E(\nu_{1})\xrightarrow{j_{0}}\mathbb{R}^{l}$. Show that there exists an $m>k,l$ such that,  if $i_{o}',i_{1}'\,\,$ are the embeddings $i_{0}':M \xrightarrow{i_{0}} \mathbb{R}^{k}\subset \mathbb{R}^{m},\,\,$ $i_{1}':M \xrightarrow{i_{1}} \mathbb{R}^{l}\subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ with extensions to the normal bundles $E(\nu_{0}')\xrightarrow{j_{0}'}\mathbb{R}^{m},\,\,E(\nu_{1}')\xrightarrow{j_{1}'}\mathbb{R}^{m},\,\,\,$ then $j_{0}',j_{1}'$ are isotopic as embeddings.

Do you know any book that states the theorem in this form? I have checked in many books ( for example in Hirsch, Lang) but I can't find the theorem in this form, everyone states the theorem for a given embedding rather than for two different embeddings.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Just let $m$ be big enough that you can isotope the two embeddings to one another. Then you're in the 1-embedding setting again, where your second normal bundle might now be different.

Comment: Do you have any specific reference for that? I am asking you because I don't have a good background in differential geometry and I want to write  this in a project. I just need a book that states that exactly

Comment: No, but using the Whitney embedding theorem with boundary, that's a *proof*.